# Creating batch files from txt files - is this right?

Tags: group-policy, batch-file, convert

Forgive me if I am completely of the rails here, but....

I am just learning about `Group Policies` and `Domain Controllers` etc. and I have a some `.bat` files, now I can edit them in notepad or any text editor.

So if I output commands say from database a `txt` file and change the extension to `.bat` will that preform the `batch file` correctly or is there a different I am suppose to create the .bat file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are basically a way to group multiple command-line commands and run them together, like this:

```
cd \
mkdir NewDir
cd NewDir
echo "content" > NewFile.txt
```

Put these commands together in a text file, change the extension to ".bat", and hey presto, you have a batch file.

If the output from the database is a series of commands like this, then yes.  Otherwise, no, that won't be a proper batch file.

Comment: Super that gives me the answer I want :-)